# How to create a generic View for different Models

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I was wondering if anyone would be able to help me with the following. I’ve had a good look around the forums and not found anything that is quiet right for my needs. I’m new to Generics and new to MVC, so please go easy on me:-).

Basically, I want to be able to pass a generic list model to my generic View which then calls a generic html helper that renders a list.

I have 2 view models which both inherit from the same abstract class…

```
public abstract class DisplayableViewModel
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
}


public class ContactListViewModel : DisplayableViewModel
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public string ContactLandline { get; set; }
    public string ContactEmail { get; set; }
}

public class ProductListViewModel : DisplayableViewModel
{
    public string ProductCompany { get; set; }
    public string ProductDesc { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public string ProductCategory { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller then creates an object of SearchViewModel which is…

```
public class SearchViewModel<T>
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Entity { get; set; }
    public PagingInfo PagingInfo { get; set; }
}
```

This is populated with objects of one of the View Models (in the example I’ve supplied it is ContactListViewModel, but it could just as likely be ProductListViewModel), some information for paging, and returns it to my View.

```
    public ViewResult List(int page = 1)
    {
        ContactListViewModel[] e = Mapper.Map<Contact[], ContactListViewModel[]>(repository.Contact.ToArray());

        SearchViewModel<DisplayableViewModel> viewModel = new SearchViewModel<DisplayableViewModel>
        {
            Entity = e,
            PagingInfo = new PagingInfo
            {
                CurrentPage = page,
                ItemsPerPage = PageSize,
                TotalItems = e.Count()
            }
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

The View does the following…

```
@using AppForProducts.WebUI.Models
@model AppForProducts.WebUI.Models.SearchViewModel<DisplayableViewModel>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "List";
}

@(Html.DataGrid<DisplayableViewModel>(Model.Entity))
<div class="pager">
   @Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("List", new {page = x}))
</div>
```

The html.DataGrid is a helper I found that simply renders a list of records of some type, so there can be 1 or more columns (if you’d like to have a look it is here… http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2009/03/03/chapter-6-understanding-html-helpers.aspx - I understand there have since been features added to MVC that does this but I’m doing this as a training exercise).

The problem I have is that it only renders a list of IDs because DisplayableViewModel is the Type parameter for the View. If I call html.DataGrid with ContactListViewModel as the Type parameter it works, but then I can’t render another Model such as ProductListViewModel using the same View. Also, if I omit the Type parameter the complier says that the type must be explicitly stated as it cannot be inferred.

Is there a way this can work generically? I really want to be able to specify some Type T in the View which gets defined as ContactListViewModel or ProductListViewModel depending on what is passed to it from the Controller.

Thanks everyone,

Jim

Comment: Why dont you let the generic type parameter get resolved via inference? Then you dont have to specify the type at all.

Comment: Hello, if I don't specify it the compliation error I get says "cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly."

Comment: Hrm, perhaps you might want to try this then: http://mvcsharp.wordpress.com/2010/02/11/building-a-data-grid-in-asp-net-mvc/ - it looks like it has a helper which would allow you to not have to specify the generic argument.

Comment: That's actually a copy of the helper I'm using and the datagrid does need the argument.

Comment: @James i am also doing the same thing i am writing the repeated functionality in Partial view. Consumer will simply call Partial View and pass Model to it. The Model in Partial view should be Dynamic. Do u find any solution to this?